# Which of these two functions is the most performance heavy

Tags: java, performance

As the title says. Which of the following two functions is the most perfomance heavy for the jvm.

```
  protected List<Car> filterByNote(String note, List<Car> cars)
  {
    List<Car> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Car c : cars)
    {
      if(c.getNotes().contains(note))
      {
        tempList.add(c);
      }
    }
    return tempList;
  }

  protected void filterByNote2(String note, List<Car> cars)
  {
    for(Car c : cars)
    {
      if(!c.getNotes().contains(note))
      {
        cars.remove(c);
      }
    }
  }
```

If someone could explain to me why one function is more heavy than the other, that would be great!

Comment: first one will work, second one will throws exception, go with first one

Comment: They do different things: one amends the list, another one returns another list. You can't compare them that way.

Comment: How do you compare them? They're performing different functions. Of course second one (if it's correct) is faster, because it's not creates any objects. And besides second one does not what it supposed to do. Why `filter` when it just removes an item from the list?

Comment: And it's dependent on what implementation of `List` you are using for `cars`, and how many values you will remove, and how many values you have in `cars`

Comment: It depends if the condition is mostly true or false.

Answer (score 1):

Usually its not a great idea to remove elements in a arraylist in a for loop, if you want something similar to the second idea, you should use an iterator:

```
Iterator<Car> it = cars.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
   Car myCar = it.next(); 
   if (something) {
        it.remove();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second method probably throws exception ConcurrentModificationException because you change list during its iteration. Try use GoogleGuava with nice function filter:

```
    protected List<Car> filterByNote(final String note, List<Car> cars) {
    return new ArrayList(Collections2.filter(cars, new Predicate<Car>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Car input) {
            return input.getNotes != null && !input.getNotes.isEmpty() &&   input.getNotes().contains(note);
        }
    }));
    }
```

Comment: Note that this method returns only a Collection, not a List. You would need to 'pour' the result of the filtering into a new list.